# Появляются отступы, которые не должны появляться при работе программы

Tags: python

Задача: написать "генератор" текстов по данным в таблице. Код на Питоне:

```
import pandas as pd
import random

df = pd.read_csv('D:/bookw.csv', sep=';')
arr = df.to_numpy()

def generateText(data, file):
    pred = random.randint(1, 30)
    flag = False
    for i in range(0, pred):
        predText = ''
        if i != 0 and flag == False:
            predText += ' '
        if i == 0:
            predText += (str)(data[0][0])
        else:
            predText += (str)(data[random.randint(0, len(arr) - 1)][0])
        predText += ', '
        flag = False
        for j in range(1, len(data[0])):
            predText += (str)(data[random.randint(0, len(arr) - 1)][j])
            if j != len(data[0]) - 1:
                predText += ' '
        ifAbz = random.randint(0, 4)
        if ifAbz == 2:
            predText += '\n'
            flag = True
        filek.write(predText)
        filek.flush()
    file.close()

filek = open(r"C:\pop\filek.txt", "w")
print(generateText(arr, filek))
```

Все бы хорошо, но при записи в файл (да и при выводе в консоль) появляются странные отступы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Почему и как это убрать?

Comment: Ещё бы понять, что тут вообще происходит в этом коде. Код написан максимально непонятно ))

Comment: Мой косяк, но не знаю, как описать это лучше) Сначала случайно определяется число предложений. Затем для первого предложения выбираем первое значение первого столбца (так надо), если любое другое предложение - случайное значение первого столбца. Далее из каждого столбца берется случайное значение. После чего берется ещё одно случайное число, и если оно равно 2, то добавляется \n. Как-то так)

Comment: Тут без детальной отладки, просто созерцая ваш код, не обойтись. А для отладки надо ваш файл с заготовками. Врят-ли кому захочется во всем этом ковыряться. Поэтому пошаговое выполнение вашей программы, с контролем результатов на каждом шаге -  ваш путь к поиска причины откложения работы вашей программы от ожидаемого. И еще совет -  для воспроизводимости результатов отладки при использовании генераторов случайных чисел не забывайте о функции seed(), иначе никогда до причины не докопаетесь. Удачи..